# Invalid API Key by using python to encode Key and using requests to GET some data

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests, hashlib

I try to acess data from an Exchange Platform with API.
I have my API_Key and my SECRET_KEY, and I have the documentation of that Platform here:
https://apidocs.exir.io/
I generate the "signature-key" just as described in the documentation under  "Authentication" chapter and then try to test it with a sample GET request with only one parameter.
Now if I run the Code I get `"message": "Access Denied: Invalid API Signature"`
Can you please help me to find the wrong thing in this code?
I think I do something wrong with `params` because if I use other GET orders without parameters it works!

Thank you in advance!

```
import time
import json
import hmac
import hashlib
import requests

API_KEY = '*****'
SECRET_KEY = '*****'
BASE_URL = 'https://api.exir.io'

timestamp = str(int(time.time()+10))

headers = {
    'api-key': API_KEY,
    'api-expires': timestamp} # see documentation under "Authentication"

PATH = '/v1/user/orders' # This ist just a simple example, which uses "params". See Exir documentation under "Get All Orders"
params = {"symbol":"btc-irt"}

string = 'GET'+timestamp+str(params) # see Exir API doumentation under "Authentication"

headers['api-signature'] = hmac.new(SECRET_KEY.encode('utf-8'), string.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

url = 'https://api.exir.io/v1/user/orders?symbol=btc-irt'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = r.json()
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of what you are doing is unnecessary, actually.  The requests library handles most of what you are trying to do.

```
import requests

API_KEY = '*****'
SECRET_KEY = '*****'
BASE_URL = 'https://api.exir.io'

timestamp = str(int(time.time()+10))

headers = {
    'api-key': API_KEY,
    'api-expires': timestamp
    }

url = 'https://api.exir.io/v1/user/orders?symbol=btc-irt'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

The library will do the encoding for you.

Comment: Thank you fpr your answer, but if I run your code, I get "Access Denied: API Signature is not provided". acording to the documentation the signature-key seems to be necessary in headers.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed the post and get request parameters. For the get request, you only need to include the params in the URL to sign. In your case it will be:

```
PATH = '/v1/user/orders?symbol=btc-irt' 
string = 'GET/' + PATH + timestamp
```